# "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: " when running Java Project on JRE(1.8)

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I am getting the following error when I run my Java project on Eclipse Oxygen with JRE build 1.8.0_152-b16.

Can any of you help me solve the problem?

Eclipse Console :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x152926f5, pid=6188, tid=0x00000264
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b16) (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.152-b16 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [seed.dll+0x26f5]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\kso8kor\PluginDevelopment_Fresh\Implementation\hs_err_pid6188.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Note : I am using 32bit eclipse and 32bit JVM on a 64bit machine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But I forgot to mention that I had checked the "hs_err_pid6188.log" file and similar questions before asking a question here.

Comment: I think you need to to enable minidumps in Java (on a Windows machine), try using this JVM option : -XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @brahimfes when I added -XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash to vmargs..I get the following :                                                                                          A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:                                                                                           Core dump written. Default location: C:\Users\kso8kor\PluginDevelopment_Fresh\Implementation\hs_err_pid5548.mdmp

Comment: I get the page doesn't exist message on clicking on the above link.

Comment: Sorry ... broken link.  See my answer

Answer (score 2):

The only (tiny) clue in the information you have provided us is that the problem occurred in some native code from a DLL called "seed.dll".  Google didn't give me any leads about what this DLL does ... or even where it comes from.

Generally speaking, JVM crashes happen for one of these reasons:

- Your codebase includes some code that is doing "unsafe" things; i.e. some native code or calls to the `Unsafe` class.  Something this code is doing is breaking the JVM.  This code might be third-party code.
- There might be a bug in the JVM itself.
- You might have a corrupted Java installation, or a hardware fault.

The best I can suggest is:

1. Find the `hs_err_pid*.log` file.
2. Using the above file and hints in the [Oracle Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html) and try to work out what your application was doing when the JVM crashed.
3. If you know about any native code or similar in your code base, see if that matches the evidence in the log file.
4. Google for examples of *similar* crashes.
5. Hire an expert.

Unfortunately, problems like this are inherently difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue after updating Java.
Solved by removing Java from PC and re-installing it from https://www.java.com